# GSON JsonSyntaxException deserializing Java Date Object

Tags: java, android, gson

I am getting a JSON String and want to convert it to a typed Object.

however i get the following deserializtion error:

```
04-02 16:20:45.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30912): 
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2014-03-25T19:10:07.1466Z
```

when trying to assign to this:

```
private Date endDateTime;
```

what would you suggest?

Comment: Try setting your date format to your Gson instance before deserialize, Gson gson=  new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(dateFormat).create();

Comment: how to use this is the date is just a field in my json. how to create the gson?

Comment: try to using SqlDateTypeAdapter as parameter on Gson:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43587232/7308789

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be a bit wrong with the date format, but take this as a guidance:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.zzz").create();
```

And then use this instance to parse your input.

Comment: how to use this is the date is just a field in my json. how to create the gson?

Comment: The idea is that your instance of `Gson` class created in the way described in my answer will handle dates as you have specified in `setDateFormat` method call. You use it in the same way you do it currently, no difference whatsoever.