# fromJson raises unparseable date exception

Tags: java, android, date, gson, unparseable

I develop android app which have client-server and DB.

I use gson to parse the objects between the server and the client.

My type of the date is j`ava.sql.date`

when I run this code (Message is an object which I created...):

```
public ArrayList<Message> getMessagesByKehilaName(String kehilaName) throws Exception {
    String result = GET(URL + "getMessagesByKehilaName?kehilaName=" + kehilaName);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<Message> am = new ArrayList<Message>(Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(result, Message[].class)));
    return am;
}
```

I get this exception:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 
>   "2011-11-05" (at offset 0)

the value on my DB is indeed `2011-11-05` and the type of my Message Date is also `java.sql.date`.

why do I have this exception?

Comment: please post your result here

Comment: The result is posted above.. i get it when i put the problematic line in try..catch block - this is the value of the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the registerTypeAdapter to be java.util.date and now it works:

```
        SqlDateTypeAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDateTypeAdapter();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(java.util.Date.class, sqlAdapter )
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
            .create();
```

I am not sure why it works. my type is sql.Date, but this is works..

Answer (score 1):

Gson default Date adapter and date format are different. You need to register the SQL Date type adapter, and also set the expected date format before deserialze the JSON.

```
SqlDateTypeAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDateTypeAdapter();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
   .registerTypeAdapter(java.sql.Date.class, sqlAdapter )
   .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
   .create();
```

Now use this `gson` object to parse the data.

### Edit

Changed the format from `yyyy/MM/dd` to `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: Did it in the beginning. but still exception is raised.