# GSON DateTypeException when Converting Date in typed in Milliseconds

Tags: rest, gson

I have a Contact class with a `created` Date property.  I'm attempting to do the following:

```
    Contact received = gson.fromJson(contactJson, Contact.class);
```

However I get the exception:

```
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1433444958703
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:81)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:66)
```

There is a similar solution to this posted already:
["Unparseable date: 1302828677828" trying to deserialize with Gson a millisecond-format date received from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671373/unparseable-date-1302828677828-trying-to-deserialize-with-gson-a-millisecond)

However it does not work for me (Will not compile).

Gson version 2.3.1

Thoughts?

TIA,
- Ole

Answer (score 2):

Found a similar solution here ([Gson: JsonSyntaxException on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878693/gson-jsonsyntaxexception-on-date)), and tweaked it slightly:

```
class JsonDateDeserializer
    implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    public Date deserialize(JsonElement json,
                            Type date,
                            JsonDeserializationContext context)
        throws JsonParseException {
        String stringDate = json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString();
        return new Date(Long.parseLong(stringDate));
    }
}

Gson gson =
    new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class,
                                          new JsonDateDeserializer())
        .create();
```

This works.  It would be great if this was the default in GSON :).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple Type Adapter and register it either with the GsonBuilder instance, or annotate with @JsonAdapter in the Contact class itself. Note that you should serialize dates as long strings because long is NOT a valid JSON type and may get trimmed to an int (which will certainly fail for most dates).

Here is how the adapter will look like:

```
public class LongDateTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Date> {
  @Override public void write(JsonWriter out, Date value) throws IOException {
    if (value == null) {
      out.nullValue();
    } else {
      out.value(String.valueOf(value.getTime()));
    }
  }
  @Override public Date read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    switch (in.peek()) {
    case NULL: return null;
    case STRING: 
      try {
        return new Date(Long.parseLong(in.nextString()));
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new JsonSyntaxException(e);
      }
    default: throw new JsonSyntaxException("invalid date" + in.getPath());
    }
  }
}
```

You can see the source code at:
https://github.com/google-gson/typeadapters/blob/master/common/src/main/java/LongDateTypeAdapter.java

Here are the tests illustrating how to use it:
https://github.com/google-gson/typeadapters/blob/master/common/src/test/java/LongDateTypeAdapterTest.java

Comment: Hello @inder123

Thank you for pointing out the alternate solutions. Could we add a simple option to the builder for searialization that specifies one of the three standard forms that Spring Boot lists in the exception?

(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ\"
\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'\"
\"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz\"
\"yyyy-MM-dd\"))

Also it would be great if GSON had a more intelligent deserialization that mirrors that of Spring Boot Marshalling and perhaps incorporates formats from other frameworks as well.

Comment: @user1684269 You should use GsonBuilder.setDateFormat() with the patterns of your choice.