# Parsing timestamp with gson for retrofit2

Tags: gson, retrofit2

I have a very simple question regarding JSON parsing. My JSON has a find with name creation and value, for example, 1456923693921, it's timestamp. How to configure Gson to parse it into Date field. Currently I have an error: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 1456923693921.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've found the fix on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671373/unparseable-date-1302828677828-trying-to-deserialize-with-gson-a-millisecond