# Android: How to deserialize this format of Date using GSON?

Tags: android, gson, deserialization

My webservice is giving me this format of Date: `1462575665220`.
How can I deserialize this using GSON?

I think that I have to use something like this:

```
new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").create();
```

But I dont know what kind of format is it.
Can I deserialize it or I have to change something in the Webservice?

Sorry for bad english, I hope you understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unparseable date: 1302828677828" trying to deserialize with Gson a millisecond-format date received from server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671373/unparseable-date-1302828677828-trying-to-deserialize-with-gson-a-millisecond)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder(); 

builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() { 
   public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
      return new Date(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong()); 
   } 
});

Gson gson = builder.create();
```