# Convert Microsoft Json Date To Java Date

Tags: java, android, gson

I consume a rest service and i get a json object , and i map json object to my java object with Gson library.
But Date Json with following format not deserialized :

```
 "/Date(1466606168687+0430)/"
```

I also checked following gson object ,but json date is not deserialized yet:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").create();

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz").create();
```

Update:
My problem is time zon for deserializing json date with timezon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unparseable date: 1302828677828" trying to deserialize with Gson a millisecond-format date received from server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671373/unparseable-date-1302828677828-trying-to-deserialize-with-gson-a-millisecond)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i use this code for date deserialization :

```
public class JsonDateDeserializer implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer<Date>{

public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    String s = json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString();

    String s1 = s.substring(6, s.length() - 2);

    String[] saa = s1.split("\\+");

    long l = Long.parseLong(saa[0]);
    Date d = new Date(l);
    return d;
}
}
```