# How to serialize Date to long using gson?

Tags: java, json, date, jackson, gson

I recently switched some of our serialization from `Jackson` to `Gson`. Found out that Jackson serializes dates to longs.

But, Gson serializes Dates to strings by default.

How do I serialize dates to longs when using Gson? Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First type adapter does the deserialization and the second one the serialization.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, (JsonDeserializer<Date>) (json, typeOfT, context) -> new Date(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong()))
        .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, (JsonSerializer<Date>) (date, type, jsonSerializationContext) -> new JsonPrimitive(date.getTime()))
        .create();
```

Usage:

```
String jsonString = gson.toJson(objectWithDate1);
ClassWithDate objectWithDate2 = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ClassWithDate.class);
assert objectWithDate1.equals(objectWithDate2);
```

Comment: Related (regarding the deserialization): http://stackoverflow.com/a/8960644/435605

Answer (score 15):

You can do both direction with one type adapter:

```
public class DateLongFormatTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Date> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Date value) throws IOException {
        if(value != null) out.value(value.getTime());
        else out.nullValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Date read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        return new Date(in.nextLong());
    }

}
```

Gson builder:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateLongFormatTypeAdapter())
        .create();
```

Comment: Nice. Especially the single type. The `nextLong()` is a bit implicit :( Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks. Actually we expect a long, and that is only a conversion shortcut provided by gson, so I don't see any problem with that. Documentation: "Returns the long value of the next token, consuming it. If the next token is a string, this method will attempt to parse it as a long. If the next token's numeric value cannot be exactly represented by a Java long, this method throws."